# display and navigate a web page from a flex tab

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, web, datagrid, navigateurl

i have a flex project that runs in using flash player 11. What i am trying to achive is to have a tab of my project which, when loaded displays a web page within the tab. I do not want to naviagate away from my project but display it within my tab layout. Is this possible? i have found plenty of info on how to do this using air but nothing with regards to my flex project not using air.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't directly possible.  The `HTML` and `StageWebView` components would do the trick, but they're AIR-only.

What you *can* do is call a javascript function using `ExternalInterface` to load your desired web page in an iframe positioned above your Flex area.

See [Div above iframe with flash content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609139/div-above-iframe-with-flash-content) for more info on putting an iframe above your flash content area.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to do, try to use [flex-iframe](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/wiki/Users-guide), but is not a good way to use iframe in flex, it will have many mask problems.